# if (key.equals ("1") || key.equals ("Circle")){

Tags: java

```
if (key.equals ("1") || key.equals ("Circle")){
```

how can i make this statement true even if I enter the string "CiRcle" or "circle"? I mean at different cases.

Comment: `equalsIgnoreCase`. Look it up in `String` Javadoc.

Comment: @TruGamer equalsIgnoreCase :)

Comment: did you try searching for "java string equal case insensitive"?

Answer (score 1):

You can try as below :

```
if (key.equals ("1") || key.equalsIgnoreCase("Circle")){
```

[More about equalsIgnoreCase](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_equalsignorecase.htm)

Answer (score 1):

```
if (key.equals("1") || key.equalsIgnoreCase("Circle")){
```

Answer (score 0):

The general syntax is

`public boolean equalsIgnoreCase(String anotherString)`

This method returns true if the argument is not null and the Strings are equal, ignoring case; false otherwise.

For your case

```
if (key.equals("1") || key.equalsIgnoreCase("Circle"))
```

[Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
if (key.equals ("1") || key.equalsIgnoreCase ("Circle"))
```

However it seems like you did not have any research or studied String methods in java. I recommend you to look at String topic in java